# Name of this type of cooling system?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, work, adiabatic, cooling

If you pump around air in a cyclic tube at a high speed, and one part of the tube is narrower than the rest of the tube, the air flow will have to increase in speed when it enters the narrow part in order to retain the mass flow rate.

This in turn requires a pressure gradient from a higher pressure at the thicker part of the tube to a lower pressure at the narrower part of the tube in order to accelerate the air. So as the gas enters the narrower part of the tube its pressure decreases and it expands. This expansion causes it to do work on its surrounding, making it loose energy and thus heat, because of adiabatic cooling.

Therefore, the narrower part of the tube will contain cooler air and thus be cooler itself than the rest of the tube, making it possible to use that part of the tube to cool other things off with.

Does this type of cooling system have a name?

Comment: Related? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63626/104696

Comment: @Farcher Related but not the same system; see my comment on @nielsnielsen’s answer.

Comment: I see that my question was downvoted. Why? Is it a bad question and if so, why is it a bad question? It’s very difficult to know how to ask better questions in the future if the people who downvote your questions don’t provide any reason for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called a vortex tube, and it has been discussed on this forum before. Search on it here to find out about the thermodynamics of it.

Comment: Thanks! It’s close but not exactly what I’m after since in a vortex tube the gas isn’t pumped around in a cyclic tube, so the system isn’t a closed system. Also, the system I’m thinking of doesn’t create any vortex as in a vortex tube.

Comment: Hmm! please keep me informed on the results of your search, I would like to know more about the system you describe.